# ATM machine request with javascript function

Tags: javascript

js community, i am relatively new to javascript. I am actually working on an ATM machine request using just basic functions, loops and conditionals but i have trouble defining the function that will calculate balance after inquiry, withdrawal and deposit.... this is the code that is giving me issues.

```
function calculateAmt(inquiry, withdrawal, deposit){
                    var availableBal = 35000; 
                    var a= inquiry(availableBal);
                    var b= deposit(availableBal);
                    var c= withdrawal(availableBal);
                    if(a){

                        availableBal =  inquiry(availableBal);
                    }
                    else if(b){
                        availableBal =  availableBal - withdrawal;
                        if(withdrawal > availableBal){
                            alert("You have insufficient funds");  
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        availableBal =  availableBal + deposit;
                    }
                    return availableBal;
                }
```

this then is the overall code which you can kindly help me go through.

```
function atmMachine(){
                var NAME = prompt("Enter your name") ; 
                var passTry = 3;
                var BANKNAME = parseInt(prompt("Dear "+ NAME+ " What is your bank name?\n 1. GTB\n2.Access\n3.Stanbic-IBTC\n4.Fidelity\n5.Sterling\n6.Skye\n7.Firstbank\n8.Others"));
                var YES_NO = 2;
                var passwordEntered = parseInt(prompt("Dear "+NAME+ ", Enter your 4 digits PIN"));
                var correct_pass = (/^[0-9]{4}$/); 
                var min_bal = 1000;

                function checkPassword(password){ //to check if the password is correct or not    
                    if(correct_pass.test(passwordEntered)){
                        optionMenu();
                    }else{
                        passTry = 3;
                        while(!(correct_pass.test(passwordEntered))){
                           alert("You don't a valid PIN, input the correct one now");
                            alert("You have only " + passTry + " chances to try");
                            passTry = passTry - 1; 

                            if (passTry === 0){
                                alert("Maximum tries exceeded, please contact your bank to retrieve your ATM card"); 
                                exit();
                                break;
                            } 
                            passwordEntered = parseInt(prompt("Dear "+NAME+ ", Enter your 4 digits PIN"));
                        }optionMenu();
                    }
                }checkPassword(passwordEntered);

                // menu selection
                function optionMenu(){
                    var SELECT_account = parseInt(prompt("Which type of account do you have?\n 1. Savings\n  2. Current\n   3. Credit"));
                   if(SELECT_account < 4){
                        var atm_functions = parseInt(prompt("Hello, customer, what can we do for you today ? \n 1. Inquiry \n 2. withdrawal \n 3. Deposit\n4. Exit"));
                        if(atm_functions==1){
                           inquiry();
                        }else if(atm_functions==2){
                            withdrawal();
                        }else if(atm_functions==3){
                            deposit();
                        }else if(atm_functions==4){
                            exit();
                        }
                        else{
                            alert("Please make a valid selection");
                        }
                    }

                }

                // to calculate the balance for before, during and after withdrawal and deposit
                function calculateAmt(inquiry, withdrawal, deposit){
                    var availableBal = 35000; 
                    var a= inquiry(availableBal);
                    var b= deposit(availableBal);
                    var c= withdrawal(availableBal);
                    if(a){

                        availableBal =  inquiry(availableBal);
                    }
                    else if(b){
                        availableBal =  availableBal - withdrawal;
                        if(withdrawal > availableBal){
                            alert("You have insufficient funds");  
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        availableBal =  availableBal + deposit;
                    }
                    return availableBal;
                }
                function inquiry(availableBal){
                    availableBal = calculateAmt(availableBal);
                    alert("Your avaialable balance is "+ availableBal);
                    toContinue();
                }
                function deposit(availableBal){
                    var deposit= parseInt(prompt("How much do you want to deposit?"));

                    if (isNaN(deposit) || deposit === " ") {
                        alert('Error: please enter a number!');
                       deposit();
                    }
                    deposit = calculateAmt(availableBal);
                    alert("You have successfully deposited "+deposit+ " ...You now have "+availableBal);
                    toContinue(availableBal);
                }
                function withdrawal(availableBal){
                  var withdrawal= parseInt(prompt("How much do you want to withdraw ? \t The minimum amount you can withdraw is 1000"));

                  if (isNaN(withdrawal) || withdrawal === " ") {
                    alert('Error: please enter a number!');
                    withdrawal(availableBal);
                    }
                    withdrawal = calculateAmt(availableBal);
                  alert("transaction is successful");
                  alert("Your remaining balance is "+ availableBal);
                  toContinue();
                }
                function toContinue(){
                    var YES_NO =  parseInt(prompt("Do you want to perform another transaction?\n 1.Yes \n 2. No"));
                    if(YES_NO === 2){
                       exit();
                    }
                    else{
                        return optionMenu(); 
                    }
                }
                function exit(){
                    alert("Thank you for patronising our ATM machine");
                    return false;
                }
            }atmMachine();
```

i ll appreciate any effort made to assist me, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I did not like reading your code - it was very messy and unorganised. Thus, I have re-written your entire program for you:

```js
var username,
 correct_pass = (/^[0-9]{4}$/),
 passTry = 3,
 currentBalance = 35000;
 
// Input a username
function atmMachineUsername() {
 username = prompt("Enter your name");
 if (username !== "" && username !== null) {
  atmMachinePassword();
 } else {
  atmMachineUsername();
 }
}
// Input a valid password
function atmMachinePassword() {
 var pswEntry = parseInt(prompt("Dear " + username + ", enter your 4 digit PIN"));
 checkPassword(pswEntry);
}
// Verify Password meets requirements
function checkPassword(userInput) {
    if (correct_pass.test(userInput)){
        selectAccountType();
    } else {
        while (!(correct_pass.test(userInput))) {
            if (passTry === 1) {
    alert("Incorrect PIN.");
             alert("Maximum tries exceeded! Your account has been locked. Contact your bank for support."); 
                exit();
                break;
            } else {
    passTry -= 1;
    alert("Incorrect PIN. Please try again.");
    alert("You have " + passTry + " chance/s to try");
             atmMachinePassword();
   }
        }
    }
}
// Select Which account type to use
function selectAccountType() {
    var accountType = parseInt(prompt("Which type of account do you have? \n 1. Savings \n 2. Current \n 3. Credit"));
 if (accountType !== "" && accountType !== null && !isNaN(accountType)) {
  selectFunction();
 } else {
  alert("Please make a valid selection");
  selectAccountType();
 }
}
// Select what the user wishes to do
function selectFunction() {
 var atmFunctions = parseInt(prompt("Hello " + username + ", what can we do for you today? \n 1. Inquiry \n 2. Withdrawal \n 3. Deposit \n 4. Exit"));
 if (atmFunctions !== "" && atmFunctions !== null && !isNaN(atmFunctions)) {
  switch (atmFunctions) {
   case 1:
    inquiry();
    break;
   case 2:
    withdrawal();
    break;
   case 3:
    deposit();
    break;
   case 4:
    exit();
    break;
   default:
    alert("Please make a valid selection");
    selectFunction();
  }
 } else {
  alert("Please make a valid selection");
  selectFunction();
 }
}
// Inquiry
function inquiry() {
 alert("Your current balance is $" + currentBalance);
 toContinue();
}
// Deposit
function deposit() {
 var depositAmount = parseInt(prompt("How much do you want to deposit?"));
 if (depositAmount !== "" && depositAmount !== null && !isNaN(depositAmount)) {
  currentBalance += depositAmount;
  alert("You have successfully deposited $" + depositAmount + "\n" + "You now have $" + currentBalance);
  toContinue();
 } else {
  alert("Error: please enter a number!");
  deposit();
 }
}
// Withdrawal
function withdrawal() {
 var withdrawalAmount = parseInt(prompt("How much do you want to withdraw? \n" + "The minimum amount you can withdraw is $1000"));
 if (withdrawalAmount !== "" && withdrawalAmount !== null && !isNaN(withdrawalAmount)) {
  if (withdrawalAmount >= 1000) {
   if (withdrawalAmount <= currentBalance) {
    currentBalance -= withdrawalAmount;
    alert("Transaction successful!");
    alert("Your remaining balance is $" + currentBalance);
    toContinue();
   } else {
    alert("You do not have sufficient funds!");
    withdrawal();
   }
  } else {
   alert("You must withdraw at least $1000");
   withdrawal();
  }
 } else {
  alert("Error: please enter a number!");
  withdrawal();
 }
} 
// Does the user wish to continue using the ATM
function toContinue(){
    var yesOrNo = parseInt(prompt("Do you want to perform another transaction? \n 1. Yes \n 2. No"));
 if (yesOrNo !== "" && yesOrNo !== null) {
     if (yesOrNo === 2){
   exit();
     }
  else {
   selectAccountType(); 
     }
 } else {
  alert("Please make a valid selection");
  toContinue();
 }
}
// Exit the ATM
function exit() {
 alert("Thank you for patronising our ATM machine");
  // To simulate a real ATM, get ready for next user
  // atmMachineUsername();
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51977233/atm-machine-request-with-javascript-function</title>
  </head>
<body onLoad="atmMachineUsername();">

</body>
</html>
```

You're Welcome.